# django-filters filter by Boolean field with DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

I'm following [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) tutorial, specifically the django-filter-backend section.

I am unable to get this to work. My goal is to retrieve a list of "containers" that have the "`in_use`" field set to True, but it keeps returning all the records in the table. I can't see what I am missing. I have added django-filters to my installed apps list and also added this to my `REST_FRAMEWORK` block:

```
'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend']
```

This is the API endpoint I'm trying to hit in postman:

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/displaydata/containers?in_use=True```](http://127.0.0.1:8000/displaydata/containers?in_use=True%60%60%60)
I've tried passing both 'True' and 'true', as well as 0s and 1s.

**views.py**

```
class ContainerViews(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id=None):
        if id:
            container = Container.objects.get(id=id)
            serializer = ContainerSerializer(container)
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            containers = Container.objects.all()
            serializer = ContainerSerializer(containers, many=True)
            filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
            filterset_fields = ['in_use']
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `queryset` and `filter_backends` as class attributes like this

```
class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Container.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContainerSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['in_use']
```

This View only serves 'list' requests (many models). If you want also serve 'get' requests (single model by ID) you need `ReadOnlyModelViewSet`

```
class ProductViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Container.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContainerSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['in_use']
```

You can use it in `urls.py` like this

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register("product", ProductViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
    ...
]
```